# why my schema.ddl is empty after hibernate3-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2

This is the directory structure of the project (maven2 is used):

```
pom.xml
/src
  /main
    /java
      Abc.java
    /resources
      hibernate.cfg.xml
      database.properties
      /META-INF
        persistence.xml
  /test
    /java
      AbcTest.java
    /resources
      database.properties
```

This is the content of `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory name="java:hibernate/SessionFactory">
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is what I have in `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence>
  <persistence-unit name="abc">
    <jta-data-source>java:/abcDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is my `Abc.java` file:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
public class Abc {
  @Id private int id;
}
```

After running `mvn clean hibernate3:hbm2ddl` I'm getting this output:

```
18:45:55,770  INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - writing 
generated schema to file: ../target/hibernate3/sql/schema.ddl
18:45:55,770  INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - schema export complete
[INFO] ————————————————————————————————————
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

File `schema.ddl` is created, and it's empty. Why? And besides that, what is wrong in my configuration files? Since when I'm trying to run unit tests with `PersistenceContext` injections they fail with `NullPointerException`. Looks like there is some problem in the configuration. Can't find any manual online…

**PS.** There are two problems, I found them already. The first one is here (extra prefix should be removed):

```
<property name="archive.autodetection">true</property>
```

The second one is more interesting. When I'm running `mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl` after compilation it works (because it has `.class` files to work with). Otherwise the schema is empty.. How to instruct this plugin to compile java classes beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are two problems, I found them already. The first one is here (extra prefix should be removed)

Indeed. So I'll skip this one.

> How to instruct this plugin to compile java classes beforehand?

Not possible (but the other way around would be, i.e. running the plugin after `compile`,   as we'll see).

The fact is that the Hibernate3 Maven Plugin, which predates annotations, has been initially designed to deal with `hbm.xml` mapping files. And that's why [`hibernate3:hbm2ddl`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2ddl-mojo.html) *invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase `process-resources` prior to executing itself*.

When using annotation instead of XML files for the mappings, the goal would indeed have to run after the `compile` phase (the [`process-classes`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) phase would be a natural candidate) but that's not the current behavior of `hibernate3:hbm2ddl`.

So you'll have to run `compile` before invoking the goal:

```
mvn compile hibernate3:hbm2ddl
```

The other option would be to bind the `hibernate3:hbm2ddl` on the build lifecycle, e.g. on `process-classes`:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase><!-- compile would also work -->
            <goals>
              <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

And then just run `process-classes` to trigger the plugin:

```
mvn process-classes
```

Comment: not working for me, i tried both ways... schema.ddl is always empty

Answer (score 0):

To fix add DTO annotated classes to hibernate.cfg.xml in its mapping configuration. This fixed the problem and worked for me right away, generated complete schema of the database.