# maven-antrun-plugin generating emty ddl file

Tags: pom.xml, maven-antrun-plugin, hibernate3-maven-plugin

I would like to generate schema sql script with maven.

Here is my persistance file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="mypersistance"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"></property>
        </properties>
        <description>Persistance descriptor</description>
        <class>test.sofiane.beans.Code</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

hibernate configuration file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="mySessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">public</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

plugin in the pom

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- Hibernatetool will generate everything before running tests -->
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <echo message="Ant target, through maven-antrun-plugin, started" />
                    <property name="maven_compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                    <property name="maven_test_classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath" />
                    <path id="hibernatetool.path">
                        <pathelement path="${maven_compile_classpath}" />
                        <pathelement path="${maven_test_classpath}" />
                    </path>
                    <taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask"
                        classpathref="hibernatetool.path" />
                    <property name="generatedByHibernate.outputDirectory"
                        value="${project.build.directory}/generated/hibernatetool" />
                    <mkdir dir="${generatedByHibernate.outputDirectory}" />

                    <hibernatetool destdir="${generatedByHibernate.outputDirectory}">
                        <classpath>
                            <path location="${project.build.directory}/classes/test/sofiane/beans" />
                        </classpath>
                        <configuration
                            configurationfile="${project.build.directory}/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
                        <hbm2ddl export="true" drop="true" create="true"
                            outputfilename="helloworld.ddl" format="true" />
                    </hibernatetool>

                    <echo message="Ant target, through maven-antrun-plugin, terminated" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The pom works fine and generate helloworld.ddl but empty unfortunately !

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

My first advice is that you should better use the `hibernate3-maven-plugin` instead of the `maven-antrun-plugin` because it includes everything that you need and is a lot more simple to use than all the configuration that you had to write with the `maven-antrun-plugin` (see [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/hibernate3-maven-plugin/) for more information about the `hibernate3-maven-plugin`).

And then, to fix your problem, I think that you can find the answer to your problem in [this post and in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805983/why-my-schema-ddl-is-empty-after-hibernate3-maven-plugin) because it seems that all the elements given will lead you to make your configuration work good.

And don't forget to bind the run of the hibernate3-maven-plugin after the compile phase, on the process-classes phase for example (see [Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)) and then just run `mvn process-classes`.